# Do you think "parent" link here should be changed to "parent site" link?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Of course, "parent" takes up less space, but the first comers may think it is a link to a board discussing children upbringing.

Answer (score 5):

This was discussed briefly in the blog comments

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

I considered and discarded a lot of the alternatives, such as

- main (too close visually to meta)
- parent site (too long)
- actual name "english", "boardgames", "cooking" (too variable in every sense)

Main isn't *bad* but consider:

> tools | chat | meta | about

vs

> tools | chat | main | about

They're *so* close visually.. ugh.

edit: since this kept coming up across the network I decided to change it from "parent" to "main".

Comment: Why not put 'main' in capital letters and 'meta' keep in small case?

Comment: Actually, now that I think on it a little more, *main* is better. It's obvious which site you're on — meta or main — so the fact that the names are both four-letter words beginning in "m" means nothing.

Comment: @brilliant I AM SURPRISED SOMEONE ON THE ENGLISH SITE WOULD PROPOSE CHANGING TO ALL CAPS TO MAKE TEXT DIFFERENT.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Why not?

Comment: @Jeff: It's a reasonable technique for SHORT pieces of text, though admittedly overused by lawyers (and presumably also by programmers back before the invention of the seventh bit :-P).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see what difference it would make. I wondered what it meant for about 0.75 seconds and then figured it out. Shorter is better in links, IMO.

Comment: this was kind of my conclusion as well -- any college educated person should be able to figure out "meta", I hope, and it is part of our mission to *educate* folks in the broadest possible sense of the word. That said if there was a slam-dunk great alternative I would consider it but I wasn't seeing that.